# Elixir Ecto : validate belongs_to between two different databases

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my umbrella app, with currently two apps, each based on its own DB...

I have a schema in `app2` referencing a `uuid` from an object of `app1`.

```
DB1 :
  Table : parent
    parent_id: uuid
    name: string

DB2 :
Table : child
    child_id: uuid
    parent_id: uuid
    name: string
```

Then the schema :

```
  schema "child" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to(:parent, Parent, type: :binary_id)

    timestamps()
  end
```

How to have the changeset validate that `parent_id` is valid and exists in its table ? I tried some things, like `assoc_constraint(:parent)` but tbh I knew it wouldn't work... Maybe I just should rethink the relationship and how it works.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No, it is not possible to have relations between different databases out of the box. So you can not have that `belongs_to(:parent, Parent, type: :binary_id)` in `Child` if `parent` is a table in a different database.

The long answer is that it *could* be possible, depending on your RDBMS, to define relations between databases. For example Postgres has some extensions like dblink and postgres_fdw that are briefly described [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/joining-data-from-multiple-postgres-databases/).

Comment: Hey, thanks. I know you can't really easily have FKs between tables in different DBs, but still, programmatic validation should be possible... So, even if it don't work right away, the question is, what should I do for it to work ? Create a custom validation function that will retrieve the `parent` and make the check ? And where would that function belongs ? Not in the changeset, that's for sure...

Comment: Yes, I think a custom validator that makes a check in another repo should work here. That validator must be called from the `changeset` function and can be defined right there in your model/schema file.